# 2 external monitors on laptop with single HDMI output and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have Dell Inspiron 5548 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. The laptop has one HDMI port and no VGA port. I would like to use 2 external screens (plus the laptop screen). Can you recommend an USB video card/adapter or an alternative solution that is compatible with Ubuntu 16.04?

Thank you.

Comment: I found something that might help you. *Look at this: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/326897-33-dual-monitors-hdmi-port* edit: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815343002

Comment: Thank you. That thread has a lot of useful information. About the Aluratek AUV200F USB, have you tried it with Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 4):

I found this one that seems to work on an Ubuntu 16 with a single HDMI: [StarTech.com USB32HD2 USB to Dual HDMI Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0725K1MHH). There is at least one purchase stating that it has: "*... tested the 4K (USB32HD4K) using the DisplayLink driver found at http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu with Ubuntu 16 and it worked like a charm.*"