# How to use StarTech USB32HD2 with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I bought this device because its reviews said it worked under Ubuntu. However, there are no drivers for ubuntu on the website.

I did install DKMS, which is the first step according to their website, before installing the drivers.

I installed the Display Link drivers, but it still didn't work. (I did restart.)

Using lsusb I found this information about the device:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0711:5601 Magic Control Technology Corp.
```

I googled for Magic Control Technology Corp linux drivers, found information about "userful" drivers, but couldn't find a download link.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of website with drivers? Is there any filter for OS, or maybe just driver for Linux?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/install-starttech-usb-dual-hdmi-on-debian-4175654386/

Comment: Can check this.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/957889/2-external-monitors-on-laptop-with-single-hdmi-output-and-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: On 20.04 I followed the instructions at `https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu` and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully got it to work by doing the following:

On your desktop, click the Ubuntu icon, type terminal, and then press Enter.

Type:

```
    sudo apt-get install dkms
```

and then press Enter.

Then download the driver from here:

https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1369

Extract the files to a chosen location. Then follow the install guidance in the txt. file

Answer (score 0):

WINDOWS ONLY: This USB-A to dual HDMI monitor adapter is only compatible with Windows operating systems and does not support macOS or Linux | External USB 3.0 (USB 3.1 Gen 1) Graphics Card Adapter to connect multiple screens

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which is "How to use StarTech USB32HD2 *with Ubuntu 18.04*". And you *specifically mention* that it will *not* work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score -1):

From official site of a product:

```
Compatibility:
Windows® 10 (32/64)
Windows 8 / 8.1 (32/64)
Windows 7(32/64)
```

There is no Linux, so where did you find an info about Ubuntu?

Comment: First answer on this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/957889/2-external-monitors-on-laptop-with-single-hdmi-output-and-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score -1):

The latest driver for ubuntu is found here: (as of Ubuntu 20.04)

https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu